# How do i get the value / the string of an element in selenium by python?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to create a bot to automatically create instagram accounts using selenium and python for learning purposes.
I have run into the problem that I cant get the text of the element that was created by the random string generator `random.org`.

I have already tried to get the txt of the element by using `elem.text()` and by `get_attribute("value")`.

```
browser.get("https://www.random.org/passwords/")
start = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/form[1]/p[5]/input[1]")
start.click()
time.sleep(2)
string5 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[5]")
string4 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[4]")
```

The html of the object is

```
<li>YWKLGQ2V</li>
```

And the xpath is

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[4]
```

When I try `string4.txt()` I get

> str is not callable

When I try `get_attribute("value")` I get

> 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `string4.text`. This variable is an element, not a string, but it may have a text value stored within it that you can access.

Comment: It may contain a list, so you could try ``string4[0].text``.